# Java GUI - Error messages keep popping up

Tags: java, swing, io, file-search

I need help at this part

```
        try{    
                FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\test.txt");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);        

              String text = txtKeyword.getText();  
              String line = null;
              boolean hasError = false;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {                                    

            if(line.contains(text)){
                String newline = "\n";
                jTextArea1.append(text + newline);
                hasError = false;
            }
            else{
                hasError = true;
            }

        }
            br.close();
            if (hasError) {
                   System.out.println("Text not found");
                } 
            }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }   }
```

Okay, I did what has been told but I'm still getting one error message each time I get the correct keyword. Is there anyway to change that? Any solutions to my problem? Or if instead of using null, what else should I use? Please guide me.. New to Java here

Comment: Suggestions to aid in your debugging and in our understanding of your problem: 1) You've got one huge class there where you should instead have 3-4 smaller more manageable and **separately testable** classes. This will help you better isolate your problems, and allow you to post less code, only the relevant code. 2) You're ignoring exceptions -- this is highly foolish, and something you should almost never do. 3) Your code formatting is pretty bad, making it hard for us to understand your code and help you. Please be strictly careful and consistent with your indentations. ... cont...

Comment: .... One empty line is more than enough anywhere, and too much whitespace as you have it is very distracting. 4) An unrelated aside, but you almost never want to use null layouts and `setBounds(...)`. It's almost a guaranteed sign that this is a newbies code because it initially seems the easier and better way to create GUI's, but with experience you'll find the exact opposite is true. Use layout managers instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm still new to Java. So, it is definitely newbie. So, I have edited my codes but 
I'm still getting one error message each time I get the correct keyword. Is there anyway to change that? Any solutions to that?

Comment: Your class is too big and formatting too poor for me to be able to get a grasp of the problem. At least put in the effort to standardize your indentations please. Four spaces for each and block, and all code on each block on the same level. Get rid of excess empty lines -- one line each. And then use debug statements or a debugger to isolate the error.

Answer (score 2):

Never just ignore exceptions

```
    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("C:\\test.txt");
    } catch(IOException e){

          // do something here - no point in continuing
    }
```

If you only want one error message then

```
 boolean hasError = true;
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {                                    

    if(line.contains(text)){

        String newline = "\n";
        jTextArea1.append(text + newline);
        hasError = false;
    }
}

if (hasError) {
   System.out.println("Text not found");
}
```

Comment: Okay, I did what has been told but I'm still getting one error message each time I get the correct keyword. Is there anyway to change that?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer.  You do not want to have `hasError = ...` in both the `if` and the `else`